# Sync local folder to Google Shared Drive

Tags: google-drive, cloud-storage

My use case is a as follows:
I have a large local folder (~2TB) on a local file server that is shared as a windows network share with several computers in the LAN. This folder is the SSOT for the data it holds.

My organization has Google Workspace. I would like to sync this folder to a Google Shared Drive so I can share it with others outside the LAN (and for rudimentary backup).

This functionality exist for a regular Google Drive (i.e a specific user's Google Drive): I can select local folders to be synced to a user's Google Drive (using Google Drive for desktop). I would like to do this but to a Shared Drive. The reason I don't want to use a user's Drive is because for some reason Google Workspace imposes storage limits on user's Google Drives, but not on Shared Drives.

More details:
Google Drive for Desktop mounts shared drives as directories. I could in principle move all the data to the Shared Drive and perhaps create network shares to it, but that seems problematic, that the SSOT becomes the mounted virtual directory from Google Drive. For example, if the Google Drive process is killed, these mounted folders disappear. This is the case even if the data is "mirrored" and not "synced" which means that the data is available offline, but still dependent on the Google Drive process.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create the folder in the shared drive and just use the local path from Google Drive Desktop to access it locally? Why is this needed?

Comment: @BlindSpots The folder already exists and is quite large and gets updated. I don't want to transfer all the data into the google drive and have it become the single source or truth. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: But, you ***do*** want to transfer it all in.  You don't want LAN users to access via drive.  Company shares don't support this and I don't see any upside & a lot of potential negatives. The more LAN users involved, the more important it is to include drive in the synchronization across all clients.  Raising the SSOT reference is interesting and also not correct.  Once you are sharing via drive, whether personal folder sync or corporate share, given you can shut off your local machine/server & still make changes via drive, how can one ever consider the local version as SSOT?

Comment: My comment about you actually **wanting** to transfer the data in, while stating you do not, is based on the fact that I don't make a distinction between sharing your folder via drive and *transferring all the data into Google Drive*.

Comment: Note that my comments are not to endorse using drive to share your files.  You can use any method (e.g. MS Sharepoint) but if you are using drive to manage sharing & synchronization, but then wanting to exclude drive from managing sharing & synchronization for a subset of users, that does not make sense to me.  Local folder sync, your previous method, may not be expected to be used in the way you were using it & possibly at scale may behave in untoward ways.  Remember that drive monitors file openings, conflicts, etc.